# Ionic - How To Check Bluetooth State Change

Tags: cordova, bluetooth, ionic-framework

Currently I'm using [cordova.plugins.diagnostic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova.plugins.diagnostic) to check whether the Bluetooth is currently On or Off. If the Bluetooth is Off then a prompt asking user to turn it On and 'Continue Button' is disabled. After it already On, how can I detect it is already On and make the Continue Button enable.

Below is a code how to detect Bluetooth is enable/disable:

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isBluetoothEnabled(function(enabled){
    console.log("Bluetooth is " + (enabled ? "enabled" : "disabled"));
}, function(error){
    console.error("The following error occurred: "+error);
});
```

Then, this is the code how to check the changes made for bluetooth state:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
     cordova.plugins.diagnostic.registerBluetoothStateChangeHandler(function(state ){

    if(state === cordova.plugins.diagnostic.bluetoothState.POWERED_ON){
        alert("Bluetooth is able to connect");
        $scope.bluetoothIsEnabled = true;
    }

    else if(state === cordova.plugins.diagnostic.bluetoothState.POWERED_OFF){
       alert("Bluetooth is Off");
       $scope.bluetoothIsEnabled = false;
   }
});
```

})

But, if I test from Off to On or On to Off, there is no any alert appear. Seems like the handler is not call back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isBluetoothEnabled(function(enabled){
    if (enabled) {
        // bluetooth already on
    } else {
        // bluetooth off
    }
}, function(error){
    console.error("The following error occurred: "+error);
});

cordova.plugins.diagnostic.setBluetoothState(function(){
    console.log("Bluetooth was enabled");
}, function(error){
    console.error("The following error occurred: "+error);
}, true);
```

html makeup

```
<button class="button" ng-disabled="!bluetoothIsEnabled" on-tap="yourFunction($event)"></button>
```

bluetooth state listen

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.registerBluetoothStateChangeHandler(function(state){
    // "unknown", "resetting", "unsupported", "unauthorized", "powered_off", "powered_on"
    if (state == "powered_on") {
        $scope.bluetoothIsEnabled = true;
    } else {
        $scope.bluetoothIsEnabled = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, you mean by putting `cordova.plugins.diagnostic.setBluetoothState` in a "Continue Button" event? So how I can make that button is enable after the bluetooth is On?

Comment: using `ng-disabled` `<button class="button"  ng-disabled="!bluetoothIsEnabled" on-tap="yourFunction($event)"></button>`

Comment: yup, i'm understand that, but how that button will enable whereas bluetoothIsEnabled is false. Because, from my scenario i mention before the bluetooth is Off. After user enable the bluetooth, this `cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isBluetoothEnabled` not callback to change the value `bluetoothIsEnabled` to true.

Comment: sorry, I miss the `registerBluetoothStateChangeHandler` function, you can use it to listen bluetooth status.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But how with Android? Because this event is only applicable for iOS.

Comment: `setBluetoothState` is `Android` only, but `registerBluetoothStateChangeHandler ` and `isBluetoothEnabled` is say support `Android` and `iOS` in the plugin document

Comment: Oh ya, I see. I'm already test it, but `registerBluetoothStateChangeHandler ` seems not calling back after I made changes in bluetooth state. I used Android version 4.1.2 and 4.4.2. I edited my question to add my new code.

Comment: if that's a plugin issue, you should post your issue to author. https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin/issues